# Image data lost when sending from android to server c# trough socket

Tags: c#, android, image, sockets, server

I'm trying to send an image from an android client to a c# server. 
But when I received the bytes on the server side, I receive it in multiple array of bytes so I have to combine the arrays in one array.
So I use :

```
            byte[] _image = Append(byteArrayIn);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_image);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Bitmap returnImage = new Bitmap(ms, true);
            pictureBox1.Height = returnImage.Height;
            pictureBox1.Width = returnImage.Width;
            return returnImage;
```

and then :

```
            Bitmap image = byteArrayToImage(mybytes);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

But when it displays the image, it only displays half of it as if some data were lost during the process.
It gives me this.
http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n560/dalex100/ss2015-03-16at11.45.53_zps9d0otfm8.jpg

Comment: Where are you combining 'the arrays' to 'one array'? You would need a loop.

Comment: @greenapps The function Append appends all the byte arrays in the List<byte[]> contained in byteArrayIn. So _image is containing all the bytes.

Comment: I've found one of my problem. The problem is that the image comes in few byte array and it will display only the first byte array. For example, if the image contained 6697 bytes, it would comes like this : 
4344, 1024, 1024 and then 305.
The first 4344 bytes would be display and the rest would be lost, even if all the bytes are appended in one array.
And that's why when all the bytes comes in one array, the image would be displayed correctly.

Comment: No. You would need a loop to begin with. You are not putting the chunks together. It is normal using TCP/IP that data comes in in chunks. You only have to put them together in a loop. You are not doing that.

Comment: I've searched for a solution on how to put everything together, but still doesn't work. Do you have a solution?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show it. Use a loop of course. That is the solution.

Comment: `mbytes` ??? Didn't see that before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem finally. The problem occurred because the operation was in the thread and the picture couldn't be completely processed before being displayed.